# Why does my Ajax function returns my entire code?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm playing with sample code from the book "Head first Ajax".  Here are the salient pieces of code:

Index.php - html piece:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="thumbnailPane"> 
      <img src="images/itemGuitar.jpg" width="301" height="105" alt="guitar" 
           title="itemGuitar" id="itemGuitar" onclick="getDetails(this)"/>
      <img src="images/itemShades.jpg" alt="sunglasses" width="301" height="88" 
           title="itemShades" id="itemShades" onclick="getDetails(this)" />
      <img src="images/itemCowbell.jpg" alt="cowbell" width="301" height="126" 
           title="itemCowbell" id="itemCowbell" onclick="getDetails(this)" />
      <img src="images/itemHat.jpg" alt="hat" width="300" height="152" 
           title="itemHat" id="itemHat" onclick="getDetails(this)" />
    </div>

    <div id="detailsPane">
      <img src="images/blank-detail.jpg" width="346" height="153" id="itemDetail" />
      <div id="description"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Index.php - script:

```
function getDetails(img){
  var title = img.title;
  request = createRequest();
  if (request == null) {
    alert("Unable to create request");
    return;
  }
  var url= "getDetails.php?ImageID=" + escape(title);
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;
  request.send(null);
}
function displayDetails() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");
      detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }else{
      return;
    }
  }else{
    return;
  }
  request.send(null);
}
```

And Index.php:

```
<?php
$details = array (
  'itemGuitar' => "<p>Pete Townshend once played this guitar while his own axe was in the shop having bits of drumkit removed from it.</p>",
  'itemShades' => "<p>Yoko Ono's sunglasses. While perhaps not valued much by Beatles fans, this pair is rumored to have been licked by John Lennon.</p>",
  'itemCowbell' => "<p>Remember the famous \"more cowbell\" skit from Saturday Night Live? Well, this is the actual cowbell.</p>",
  'itemHat' => "<p>Michael Jackson's hat, as worn in the \"Billie Jean\" video. Not really rock memorabilia, but it smells better than Slash's tophat.</p>"
);
if (isset($_REQUEST['ImageID'])){echo $details[$_REQUEST['ImageID']];}
?>
```

All this code does is that when someone clicks on a thumbnail, a corresponding text description appears on the page.

Here is my question.  I have tried to bring the `getDetails.php` code inside `Index.php`, and modify the `getDetails` function so that the `var url` be `"Index.php?ImageID="...`
.  When I do that, I get the following problem:  the function does not display the snippet of text in the array, as it should.  Instead it reproduces the entire code - the webpage, etc - and then at the bottom the expected snippet of text.

Why is that?

PS:  OK, I now understand my problem, thanks to the two responses below.  When I call the url `"Index.php?ImageID="...`, I am not just loading the part that correspond to the `$_GET`.  I am loading the entire page, now with a non-null `$_GET`  value.  This makes it clear why I need to have a separate page just for the stuff I want to add.

Comment: Well, in your full `index.php` do you ever instruct it _not_ to return the rest of the content based on some condition?  Can you share the actual full `index.php` instead of displaced snippits therein?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you recognize the request for image info, you spit out the data, but you do nothing to prevent the rest of the script from running. You could change

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ImageID'])){echo $details[$_REQUEST['ImageID']];}
```

to something like

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ImageID'])){
  echo $details[$_REQUEST['ImageID']];
  exit;
}
```

Still, I'd recommend using a separate URL for the image info. A URL should describe the resource found there, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's because you're requesting the entire page, the Ajax is successful, and is returning the page to you, as you've requested.

Ajax isn't meant for same-page requests. Keep the processing files separate from the index file.